# FOS Rest Bundle AccessDeniedListener not called

Tags: symfony

I've been scratching my head about this for a while. I was looking at Symfony's exception handling and checking what listeners are configured. I saw that FOS Rest Bundle provides an `AccessDeniedListener` which is defined in their services definition as

```
    <service id="fos_rest.access_denied_listener" class="%fos_rest.access_denied_listener.class%">
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
        <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="request" />
        <argument>%fos_rest.access_denied_listener.formats%</argument>
        <argument>%fos_rest.access_denied_listener.unauthorized_challenge%</argument>
        <argument>%twig.exception_listener.controller%</argument>
        <argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="null" />
    </service>
```

However even putting a `die()` inside the `getSubscribedEvents` of this has no effect so I'm guessing it's being ignored for some reason. I thought the `getSubscribedEvents` method of any class with the `kernel.event_subscriber` tag would be called, is this wrong?

I also tried putting the service definition inside my own bundle, but didn't work.

Just looking at the symfony `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener` I can see they are adding the `kernel.event_subscriber` tag and this works, the subscriber is called as expected. Actually putting a breakpoint on the `addSubscriber` method in the symfony EventDispatcher shows me that no subscribers are being added at all. I'm very confused about all this and maybe have misunderstood how subscribers / listeners work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a case of not reading the docs well enough, it wasn't called because it has to be enabled

**config.yml**

```
unauthorized_challenge: "Basic realm=\"Restricted Area\""
access_denied_listener:
    json: true
```